# Toggle between different divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

I need a solution for toggle between divs. I have a sidebar with a group of buttons. When I enter the page with the sidebar I only want the div with the button group to appear, but when I press for example Info I want the info div to appear and the other divs to disappear, and when I press the back button on the Info div I again only want the button group to appear.

```css
.info {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.about {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h3>Metadata & additional services</h3>
      <div class="button-group" id="showall">
        <button class="activeButton" id="info-button">Info</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Quotes</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Additional</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Additional</button>
      </div>
      <div class="info" id="info">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Author:</li>
          <li>Title:</li>
          <li>Content:</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="back-button">Back</button>
      </div>
      <div class="about" id="about">
        <h1>about</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#info-button").click(function () {
          $("showall").hide();
          $("#info").show();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Your `$("showall").hide();` is missing a `#`. It should be `$("#showall").hide();`

Comment: I added the #, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the id identifier in your `.click` function. If you want the info div hidden on page load, make sure to set it to display none, then add another event handler for the `#backBtn`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#info-button").click(function () {
          $("#showall").hide();
          $("#info").show();
        });
        $("#backBtn").click(function () {
          $("#showall").show();
          $("#info").hide();
        });
      });
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.about {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
   <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h3>Metadata &amp; additional services</h3>
      <div class="button-group" id="showall">
        <button class="activeButton" id="info-button">Info</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Quotes</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Additional</button>
        <button class="activeButton">Additional</button>
      </div>
      <div class="info" id="info">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Author:</li>
          <li>Title:</li>
          <li>Content:</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="back-button" id="backBtn">Back</button>
      </div>
      <div class="about" id="about">
        <h1>about</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#info-button").click(function () {
          $("showall").hide();
          $("#info").show();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you link to a JS fiddle or Codepen? The code is working just fine in my answer snippet.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now. I had just fogotten to add the jquery script in the header.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to upvote/approve if my answer helped you :)